# Is it safe and secure to use 18.04 mini.iso minimal instalation for i3?

Tags: 18.04, security, swap, ubuntu-minimal, i3-wm

I took the 18.04 mini.iso, did a basic install. Selected automatic security updates. On software selection screen I selected nothing. Rebooted, installed xinit, i3 (and some x11 utilities package, sorry, cannot find it now), pulseaudio, cups, ... and I would like to use it as desktop. Is it safe?
I did lsblk and I have no swap probably. Is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I3 is only a window manager and has nothing to do (directly) with the security of your system.

You can implement a lot of different directives for better security, like using a non-root user for daily tasks (root only when needed), setting permissions correctly, if you feel, create some iptable rules to prevent connection to your machinem, etc.

Check the services that are running in your machine with 'ps' and which ports in your system are open using 'netstat -tunlp', you can check which process is opening each port running it with sudo

Swap also has nothing to do with security, you can read more about it here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap

Answer (score 1):

It's safe... but you should configure iptables to drop incoming traffic if you will be on a network that you don't control.

Here are some very basic instructions to get you started:

```
# Drop all traffic unless explicitly allowed
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP

# Allow existing connections to stay connected
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow loopback connections
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Open any other ports you want to allow to come in, for example SSH, HTTP, and HTTPS
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Now check your work:

```
iptables -L
```

Start over if you need to:

```
iptables -X -F
```

For more detail, see: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...